# Where do I find MVC4 templates for download and how do I install them?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-templates

I am somewhat confused. Searched a bunch of ASP.NET related sites but could not find the answer. I must be missing some search word..

I want to find a gallery of MVC4 templates (free/cheap) and apply them to my project. Where do I do that from? I found one codeplex project (http://mvccontribgallery.codeplex.com/), but when I tried applying by copying, there were a bunch of errors (it uses something called SiteMaster, while my project seems to be using something called _layout).

I see a ton of references to people using them, applying them, but I must be missing something very fundamental since I can't even figure out how to find a list of downloadable templates.

What are the simple 1/2/3 steps for finding/getting/installing a template on my MVC4 project?

Comment: no documentation, no release, just forget them.

Comment: i talking about mvccontribgallery.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by mvc4 templates? I'm assuming you mean "website template". With MVC you can use any html template, there's no specific template for MVC (that's why you're not finding any of it). You just find any website template and adapt it to mvc context (put css and images under "Content" folder and put html code in _layout and use it like masterpage), not hard to do at all. In fact, so easy to do after you get the idea that no one publish a specific adapted version :)

Comment: Huh. Okay. That's awkward.

Answer (score 1):

You should be looking for a suitable HTML template instead of an MVC specific template.

Once you have that, you will need to modify you master template (usually Views/Shared/_layout) to use the HTML and CSS contained within the template you have chosen.

Answer (score 1):

For MVC3 or MVC4 you don't need to download any template. **Just [install MVC4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4) in your visual studio 2010 version on higher and then choose option create new project** and that is that. See this below screen capture:

[image]

**Microsoft will provide you the default MVC project architecture or in your term MVC template automatically when you choose any of above option marked in red box.**

Comment: He's referring to website layouts for an MVC project, not project templates.

Comment: It's not absolutely clear what he was meaning in the question

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

(note: if you have Asp.Net MVC 4, 3 won't install right (for me anyway), so uninstall and install in order).

http://tedgustaf.com/blog/2011/4/installing-asp-net-mvc3-on-visual-studio-2010-sp1/

Comment: Also be sure to choose the correct target framework in the drop down on the top of the "New Project" dialog.